# Android EditText initial scroll position is not 0

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I am new on android development and now using `EditText` for long text with `singleLine`. But initial scroll does look good as following screenshot:

[image]

After I scroll, it is normal.

[image]

Is there anyway to put initial scroll position 0?
(I am sorry if this was asked already. I didnt find any solution yet)

Thank you

**EDITED:**

This is the latest xml:

`<EditText
    android:id="@+id/self_intro"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_self_intro"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:drawablePadding="7dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />`

Comment: you mean till you scroll edit text is like in the first image . right?

Comment: Yes, first screenshot is how it looks until I scroll. Second one is after I scroll :)

Comment: What's your `minLines`, `maxLines` and `lines` set to for the `TextView`?

Comment: can you post your xml code

Comment: @JustinMitchell I don't have `minLines` and `lines`,  just `maxLines = 1`

Comment: @CharukaSilva Sure I can, I've just edited the question

Comment: Just remove android:inputType="textMultiLine" and it works like a charm.

you can also remove the android:singleLine="true" which is now deprecated instead of you can use  android:lines="1". when you use lines="1" there is no need to use maxLines="1".

Comment: @AndyDeveloper thank you for your answer. But the result is still same :(

Comment: @MuhridinIbragimov try to remove all scrollbar properties.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I tired it and no luck :( I updated the xml in the answer

Comment: @MuhridinIbragimov the same thing i was used in my code it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Yeah It should work, I don't get what the problem is.